# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context

I create a hook inside the `ThemeDoc` component then using React Context I try to get the value of the hook inside the `SideBarBlurChange` component I have a lot and all other hooks work fine except the `RangeBlur` hook when I try to get the `RangeBlur` value I get the error

**Cannot read property 'toFixed' of null**

like me ponel the problem is that instead of getting the value of the hook (in my case, the value 40, a prime number), I get null and I can't understand why, but first of all, how will I provide the code, I would like to demonstrate screenshots

[image]

[image]

All other hooks work fine by the way, I would also like to provide a link to the npm package [react-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-range) which I use in `SideBarBlurChange`

I removed unnecessary details from the components to make it easier to read the code, I think they are not useful

**ThemeDoc.js**

```
export const CounterContext = createContext([]);

export default function ThemeDoc(props) {

    const [RangeBlur, SetRangeBlur] = useState(localStorage.getItem(40));


    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("RangeKey", RangeBlur);
    })

    return (
        <div className="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
            <CounterContext.Provider value={{
                RangeBlurValue: [RangeBlur, SetRangeBlur],
            }}>
                <SideBar {...props} />
                <PageContent {...props} />
            </CounterContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**SideBarBlurChange.jsx**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {CounterContext} from "../../../Theme/ThemeDoc";

export default function SideBarBlurChange(props) {

    const { RangeBlurValue } = React.useContext(CounterContext);
    const [RangeBlur,] = RangeBlurValue;

    const [values, SetValues] = useState([RangeBlur])

    const SaveChanges = () => {
        alert(values)
    }

        return (
            <>
                <div
                >
                    <output style={{ marginTop: "30px" }} id="output">
                        {values[0].toFixed(1)}
                    </output>

                    <button onClick={() => SaveChanges()}>Save</button>
                </div>
            </>
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `useState` and `localStorage.getItem` is incorrect. Change:

```
const [RangeBlur, SetRangeBlur] = useState(localStorage.getItem(40));
```

...to:

```
const [RangeBlur, SetRangeBlur] = useState(localStorage.getItem("RangeKey") ?? 40);
```

As you currently had it, you're trying to retrieve a storage value using the key `40` when you actually want that to be your default initial state. Since you don't have a localStorage key of `40` `localStorage.getItem` returns `null`, hence that is passed in as the initial state value to `RangeBlur`, and that's why the `toFixed` call fails later on since you can't call `null.toFixed(...)`

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question by the way now I get the error **values [0] .toFixed is not a function** I checked the value but it still gives "null" but already in quotes, to be honest, I'm a little confused

Comment: Try clearing your localStorage (`localStorage.clear()`); you might have bad data in there from earlier, like a string with the value `"null"`.